# Login failed while connecting to a SQL Server Engine (untrusted domain)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-8.1

We have in our office 3 PC's and 1 tablet (with Windows 8). On PC's we have installed SQL Server. All devices are in the same workgroup.

One of the computers acts as a server and everyone connect to that computer. However, if we try to connect from the tablet, it shows an error "login failed" because it detects that is an untrusted domain. But the tablet is on the same workgroup.

What could be the problem?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

The solution was to use the same local user/password on the tablet as on the server.